# How should I call NuxtServerInit correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

There is such code in the VUEX repository:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  z: 'sdfjkhskldjfhjskjdhfksjdhf',
});

export const mutations = {

  init_data_for_firmenistorie2 (state, uploadDbFirmenistorieData){
    state.z = uploadDbFirmenistorieData;
  },


};

  async nuxtServerInit ({commit}) {
    console.log('111');
    commit('init_data_for_firmenistorie2', 123)
  }


}
```

My question is:
How should I call to nuxtServerInit in such a way that I can use it to rewrite the value of state z?
P.S. Right now my code is not working.

Answer (score 3):

If your `store/index.js` has an action `nuxtServerInit`, then `Nuxt` will invoke it.

So your code ends up looking like

```
export const state = () => ({
  z: 'sdfjkhskldjfhjskjdhfksjdhf',
});

export const mutations = {
  init_data_for_firmenistorie2(state, uploadDbFirmenistorieData) {
    state.z = uploadDbFirmenistorieData;
  },
};

export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit({ commit }) {
    console.log('111');
    commit('init_data_for_firmenistorie2', 123);
  },
};
```

Comment: If this storage file has the name "company_history.js" - I don't understand what should I write in storage index.js?
right now I have in index file something like that:
http://joxi.ru/zANMJPYsvpWQZ2

Comment: Change the name of the file `indexPage.js` to `index.js` and create export const actions... like I have showed above

Comment: http://joxi.ru/RmzB1JxTY9gW0m
If I changed the name I have a problem like that:
http://joxi.ru/DmBgybLhJVnN52
Because of it I do that name(IndexPage).

Comment: Index.js state becomes part of the rootstate and you can access it from there.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#module-local-state

Comment: And dispatching action is just the matter of removing the prefix. Since its root level action. Just do $store.dispatch('init_state_for...')

Comment: I didn't understand on your link what should I write in my code for correctly getting data exactly on "index page"?
http://joxi.ru/MAjdQLoHj694Rm
Where should I pay attention on your link?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/nAypkNxHgx6wY2
that does not work.
http://joxi.ru/V2V64PLCdgZKD2

Comment: Show the content of index.js

Comment: I showed it on the previous screen
http://joxi.ru/nAypkNxHgx6wY2

Comment: You don't have an action there. You have a mutation. Mutations are committed. Man, give the vuex documentation a good read first. It will help.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/L215QxzHR71wn2
not working.
http://joxi.ru/BA0QjX0IMyk1Yr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201470/discussion-between-prashant-and-mike-kharkov).

Answer (score 0):

Well you create a actions object, and then you put your `nuxtServerInit` in there:

```
export const actions = {
   nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context){
      vuexContext.commit('init_data_for_firmenistorie2', 123);
   }
}
```

With `context` you can additional have access to for example `params`, `routes`, `redirect` etc.
The docs: https://nuxtjs.org/api/context